# What is the relationship between hook menu() and menu_link_save()?

Tags: routes

I am trying to create a menu using code in D7 ([see my related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24131)) and have found that these two Drupal API functions have different arrays for the $item variable. My intent is to create a three level menu hierarchy but with all of the associated paths being the same format `/name/%/something` so that I can use views to refine the content.  In hook menu, the parents are defined using the Path name (eg. `parent/child/something`).  In menu_save_link, the hierarchy appears to be established using the `pid` array value in $item. Hook_menu is called when my custom module is read by drupal and the menu links are established.  What I am wondering is if `menu_link_save`, could be used to do the same thing but with the same path style for all links, rather than a parent-child pattern?

I have been trying to trace the logic between the two functions in the API, but have not found the link between them.  My thinking is that `menu_link_save`is used by `hook_menu` after some preprocessing and that I might be able to define a uniform paths and establish the hierarchy through the `pid`.  Failing that, is there another way to alter the paths and preserve the hierarchy?

Comment: Is setting up this a one-time thing, or an ongoing task?

Comment: It's a one time thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't totally get what you are trying to do, but I think this will do what you want.

- Use your `hook_menu()` to just set up the paths that Drupal needs to respond to. Don't actually add the paths to a menu.
- Make a new menu in the UI.
- Loop through the items you need and call `menu_link_save()`

This should get you started

```
$item = array(
    "link_path" => "some/path/to/a/page",
    "link_title" => "Some Title",
    "menu_name" => "menu-the-name-of-the-menu",
    "plid" => $plid,
    "router_path" => "some/path/to/a/page",
);

$sql = "
    SELECT menu_links.mlid
    FROM {menu_links} menu_links
    WHERE menu_name = :menu_name AND plid = :plid AND link_path = :link_path
";

$result = db_query($sql, array(
    ":menu_name" => "menu-the-name-of-the-menu",
    ":link_path" => $item["link_path"],
    ":plid" => $plid
));

$record = $result->fetchObject();  

if (isset($record->mlid) && $record->mlid > 0) $item["mlid"] = (int) $record->mlid;

menu_link_save($item);
```

When your loop is done, call `menu_cache_clear_all()`.

This is the inner loop from a module I have to automagically build some menus for non-node pages.  I also have the full function wired up via hook_menu, so people can rebuild as needed.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. If I understand, by your first bullet item I would invoke hook_menu to assemble the menu hierarchy using the path to tell Drupal the parent child relationship by the segments of the path /parent/child/etc. and assign it the type of MENU_CALLBACK so that it does not actually construct an actual menu.   To clarify my intent, I want to change the path for the item from /parent/child/...  to /name/id# and still preserve the parent-child relationship. Based upon what your answer, it appears I can edit a menu item created by hook_menu using menu_link_save?

Comment: Putting it another way, I assume that hook-menu defines the parent in plid and not longer relies on the link_path so it can be changed without altering the parent-child relationship?

Comment: Yeah, I think you can do this.  In my case, I was dealing with the auto taxonomy term pages that taxonomy_menu created, and then I have to arrange these inside another menu.

Comment: That is exactly where I started.  So in your case, you used Taxonomy_menu and then changed the link_path and menu name for the items?  I also note that you are changing the $pid.  Isn't the taxonomy hierarchy already in the the database from when hook-menu was called?  Or did you need to change it for another reason?

Comment: In my cases, I needed to add them to a new menu.  I messed with $plid b/c I needed to rework the parent/child thing in the new menu.  Remember, menu_router sets up the callbacks, menu_links has the actual menu entries.  It helps if you do some experiments and see the changes to both those tables via MySQL Query Browser (or similar tool).

Answer (score 3):

They're slightly different concepts to be honest; the items defined in `hook_menu()` are saved in the `menu_router` table, while `menu_link_save()` saves items to the `menu_links` table.

They come together in [`menu_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7):

1. `hook_menu()` is invoked through the [`menu_router_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_router_build/7) function to get a list of router items
2. The router items are saved to the database using [`_menu_router_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/_menu_router_save/7)
3. The menu links are generated/updated using [`_menu_navigation_links_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/_menu_navigation_links_rebuild/7); the menu router items are passed to this function to build the links.
4. Finally the caches are cleared.

There doesn't seem to be any way to pass custom data from the router items to the links I'm afraid, and I don't think `hook_menu()` supports the sort of hierarchy you're trying to build natively.

Comment: Is there a way (hook) to access and modify the path after the menu items are created so that I can change the name and preserve the lineage?

Comment: I'm not sure if they'll get what you want but you might want to look at [`hook_menu_link_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_insert/7) and [`hook_menu_link_update`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_update/7)