# Override menu item weight (bring it to same level as 'user' link) that has user/% path and has to be in user-menu

Tags: routes

I need a menu item living in the user-menu, has path like 'user/%something' but i dont want it to have "My account" link as parent (that has path 'user')

i can only change that through the administration but this is not an accepted answer...

Any thoughts?

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the documentation of [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) doesn't mention it, the `plid` attribute can be used for specifying the ID of the parent menu link. You can set it to *0* if you don't want your menu item to have a parent.

It's probably not included in the documentation, because it's problematic to know the menu link ID (`mlid`) on that level where you use `hook_menu()`. It's an incremental identifier in the database, so there is no guarantee that it will always be the same (e.g. after reinstalling the site if you work on an installation profile). So I don't think it's a good idea to make a use of this attribute, except of course when you have this simple use case that setting it to zero does the job.

Answer (score 1):

pff got it

had to

```
hook_menu_link_alter
```

and changes this link's plid like:

```
/**
* Implements hook_menu_link_alter().
*/
function YOURMODULE_menu_link_alter(&$item) {
  if ($item['link_path'] == 'user/some-path') {
    $item['plid'] = '0'; // instead of '2' (My Account menu item)
 }
}
```

drupal is a pain sometimes... but we love it anyway

Comment: Are you creating the menu item in `hook_menu()`? Because then you can specify the `plid` there.

Comment: How? there is no such option in hook_menu()

Comment: I believe you can do it in the same way as you did in your `hook_menu_link_alter()` implementation. Just use the `plid` key, give it a try! ;)

Comment: you are absolutely right , its the same array after all ...., why dont you make it an answer?